# Subprojective Orlicz sequence spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

A Banach space $X$ is ***subprojective*** if every infinite dimensional closed subspace $Y$ of $X$ contains an  infinite dimensional subspace $Z$ which is complemented in $X$.
I am interested in conditions on an Orlicz function $M$ implying that the Orlicz sequence space $\ell_M$ is subprojective.

A concrete case: $M_a(t)=t^2|\log t|^a$ $(a>0)$. In this case, $\ell_{M_a}$ is hereditarily $\ell_2$. So the question is if every infinite dimensional closed subspace of $\ell_{M_a}$ contains a subspace isomorphic to $\ell_2$ and complemented in $\ell_{M_a}$.
Moreover, the dual space $\ell_{M_a}^*$ is isomorphic to $\ell_{M_a^*}$, where $M_a^*(t)=t^2|\log t|^{-a}$ is also an Orlicz function.

Are $\ell_{M_a}$ and $\ell_{M_a}^*$ subprojective?

Comment: $\ell_{M_a}$ has type $2$, so you get complementation for free.

Comment: $\ell_{M_a^*}$ has cotype $2$ (it even embeds into $L_1$), so every block basis that spans a Hilbert space is complemented. Thus both questions have affirmative answers.

Comment: Those comments are from memory. You'll have to track down references. For the second (which gives the first) I think a paper of Krivine and Dacunha Castelle is where the embedding is proved.

Comment: The space $\ell_{M_a}$ has cotype 2, hence $\ell_{M_a}^*$ has type 2. See, for example, Corollary 13 in E. Katirtzoglu [J. Math. Anal. Appl. 226 (1998), 431-455].

Comment: Oh, sorry; I had it backwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Bill pointed out the answer is Yes. In this particular example, the situation is even simpler: every normalized block sequence $(u_i)$ has a subsequence equivalent to either uvb of $\ell_M$ or to of $\ell_p$. This is easy to see since the set $C_{M}=\{t^p\}$. Specifically, if $\|u_i\|_{\infty}>0$ then the sequence is equivalent to $\ell_M$, and otherwise to $\ell_p$. In both cases, those sequences are complemented. See Lemma 2.5 of this [paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2014-142-05/S0002-9939-2014-11903-4/S0002-9939-2014-11903-4.pdf) for the calculation. Moreover, in the paper it is shown that this space (and a class of similar Orlicz spaces called $p$-regular) is complementably homogeneous.

Answer (score 1):

I think not: $\ell_M$ has not type 2 for the same reason that the Kalton-Peck space $Z_2$ has not type 2: the sum of n vectors of the canonical basis has norm $\sqrt{n}\log n$